# Struts2, convert s:select list to display Tag column

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, pagecontext

I have the following selection list in jsp:

```xml
<td>
    <s:select list = "models" 
         listValue = "modelName"
           listKey = "modelId" 
          multiple = "true" 
              name = "models" />
</td>
```

I chose to implement pagination with `display Tag` library, so I want to convert it in display column and show one ore more models from the list. How can I do this? Below is my display table with the other columns:

```xml
<display:table name = "cars" 
         requestURI = "/listCar.action" 
           pagesize = "10">

     <display:column property = "name" title = "name" />

     <display:column titleKey = "models" >
         <!--------------model list?-------------->
     </display:column> 

     <display:column property = "year"  title = "year" />

</display:table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to make DisplayTag pushing the value in a context you can access:

> #### [Implicit objects created by table](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_implicitobjects.html)
>
> **If you add and `id` attribute the table tag makes the object
>   corresponding to the given row available in the page context** so you
>   could use it inside scriptlet code or some other tag. Another implicit
>   object exposed by the table tag is the row number, named `id_rowNum` .
>
> These objects are saved as attributes in the page scope (you can
>   access it using `pageContext.getAttribute("id")` ). They are also
>   defined as nested variables (accessible using `<%=id%>` ), but only if
>   the value of the id atribute is not a runtime expression. The
>   preferred way for fetching the value is to always use
>   `pageContext.getAttribute()`.
>
> If you do not specify the id attribute no object is added to the
>   pageContext by the table tag

Then you need to access that context. In Struts2, the `pageContext` is available through `#attr`:

> #### [Struts 2 Named Objects](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Struts2NamedObjects):
>
> `#attr['foo']` or `#attr.foo`
>
> Access to `PageContext` if available, otherwise searches `request`/`session`/`application` respectively

So the code would be:

```xml
<display:table   id = "currentRowInPageContext"
               name = "cars" 
         requestURI = "/listCar.action" 
           pagesize = "10">

     <display:column property = "name"  title = "name" />

     <display:column titleKey = "models" >
         <s:select list = "%{#attr.currentRowInPageContext.models}" 
              listValue = "modelName"
                listKey = "modelId" 
               multiple = "true" 
                   name = "models" />
     </display:column>                                                

     <display:column property = "year" title = "year" />

</display:table>
```

Nowadays, however, there are better alternatives than DisplayTag, for example [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and [jQuery jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/); for the latter there is also a plugin ([struts2-jquery-grid-plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action)) that helps you use the grid without knowing its syntax, just knowing struts2 tags.

Comment: Great Andrea, it worked once more ;) Well I wanted to make this fixed and had in mind from the start to try jQuery DataTables alternative.

Comment: Yeah, try scouting them both (datatables and jqgrid) in your next free time window, they're 10 years newer than displaytag and you can clearly see it in many features.